# Function recv from browser socket, but stores nothing in buffer

Tags: c++, sockets, http, header, recv

I need to receive a HTTP request from my browser, when I run localhost:8228 it works fine, I receive the header in the buffer and am able to write it to the console and even echo send it back to the browser. But when I try reading a request from a actual webpage, buffer is empty, it prints nothing.

I have a simple main that looks like this:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char buffer[1024*1024] = {0};
  int port_number = 8228;

  if (argc == 1)
    std::cout << "Using default port number, 8228." << std::endl;
  else if (argc == 3) {
    port_number  = atoi(argv[2]);
  } else {
    std::cout << "::Error::" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Wrong number of arguments." << std::endl;
    exit[0];
  }

  AppSocket app;
  app.Start((int)port_number);
  app.AcceptCall();
  int request_size = app.ReceiveRequest(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

  return 0;
}
```

My AppSocket functions would be:

```
void AppSocket::Start(int port) {
  // Create a socket
  listening_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (listening_fd == -1) {
    std::cerr << "Could not create a socket." << std::endl;
    exit(-1);
  }
  app_hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
  app_hint.sin_port = htons(port); 
  inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &app_hint.sin_addr);  
  if (bind(listening_fd, (sockaddr*)&app_hint, sizeof(app_hint))< 0) {
    std::cerr << "Cannot bind to IP/port." << std::endl;
    exit(-2);
  }
  std::cout << "Socket has been bound." << std::endl;

  if (listen(listening_fd, SOMAXCONN) == -1) {
    std::cerr << "Cannot listen." << std::endl;
    exit(-3);
  }

  std::cout << "Listening to port " << port << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Your socket is: " << listening_fd << std::endl;
}

void AppSocket::AcceptCall() {
  client_size = sizeof(client_addr);
  client_fd =
         accept(listening_fd, (sockaddr *)&client_addr, &client_size);

  if (client_fd < 0) {
    std::cerr << "Error connecting to client." << std::endl;
    exit(-4);
  }

  std::cout << inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr)
            << " connected to port "
            << ntohs(client_addr.sin_port) << std::endl;

  close(listening_fd);
}

int AppSocket::ReceiveRequest(char *buffer, int max) {
  std::cout << "Client is: " << client_fd << std::endl;
  memset(buffer, 0, buff_size);    //clear buffer

  int n = recv(client_fd, buffer, buff_size, 0);
  if (n < 0)
  std::cerr << "A connection issue has occured." << std::endl;

  if (n == 0)
    std::cout << "Client disconected." << std::endl;

  std::cout << "recv return " << n << std::endl;
  std::cout << buffer << std::endl;

  return n;
}
```

When I run and access a webpage I get this:

```
Using default port number, 8228.
Socket has been bound.
Listening to port 8228
Your socket is: 3
127.0.0.1 connected to port 37522
Client is: 4
recv return 3
```

None of the questions I've read seem to work for me...

edit: sorry one of the lines in the main code wasn't copied. 
How can I receive repeatedly? A while loop? I tried that and just kept receiving nothing.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us. The code you show won't do what you claim it does (for example it doesn't call `ReceiveRequest` at all).

Comment: TCP is a streaming protocol; you need to `recv` repeatedly until you have received everything.

Comment: `std::cout << buffer << std::endl;` -- In addition, if the client is sending binary data, i.e. data that may contain embedded nulls, outputting the information this way will not show everything you've received.

Comment: If the problem was receiving repetedly shouldn't I have received something at least? I receive nothing...

Comment: But the output you show says that `recv` returns `3`, which means your program have received *at least* three bytes. How are you connecting to this server? What do you send to the server?

Comment: @LuisaSinzkerFantin *I receive nothing...* -- Not according to your output -- your output shows `3`.  You are relying on what your terminal, i.e. `cout` is showing you and if those characters are not displayable, you're not going to see anything.  You should try and display the byte values, not the characters themselves.

Comment: I'm not connected to the internet yet, just the browser I just want the header for the request, I'm listening to the requests, my application is working as a server.

Comment: I ran Gdb it show the memory as just "" for the buffer address

Comment: That just means that the first character was a NUL byte. Does the browser try to use HTTPS?

Comment: @RolandW It's supposed to be a HTTP website, I use firefox and configure the browser to use proxy at port 8228 for HTTP protocols specifically, but when I do that no other protocols work, odd. Could firefox be trying to send it as HTTPS even though it isn't?

Comment: Try http://localhost:8228/ without a proxy.

Comment: @RolandW it works with localhost: Client file descriptor is: 4
recv return 314
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8228
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

Comment: I've tried setting localhost:8228 as a proxy and accessing google.com via http using `netcat -l -p 8228` to simulate your code, and it works for me. Getting a HTTP GET request.

Comment: Indeed it was the browser. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The code works, what was happening is that the firefox proxy settings were wrong, when I ran localhosts it worked fine because it was actually working as the server due to the port it was using but when trying to access a "real" website it didn't. After configuring it correctly it did just what it's supposed to do.